# How to send the mail with attachment in spring

Tags: java

when is trying to send the mail using zip mime type is getting some random format attachment. so tried to change the mime type by hard coding, need to know how to get the mime type from bytearraysource object

```
package com.mail.send;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MailImpl {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
    JavaMail javaMail=(JavaMail) context.getBean("JavaMail");
    System.out.println("after bean creation");
    String to="abc@gmail.com";
    String cc="xyz@gmail.com";
    String subject="Pdf notification";
    String content="PDF has been generated";
    boolean flag = true ;
    File file =new File("E:\\Sample.pdf");

    //byte [] sample=null;

    /*start of modify*/
     FileInputStream fin = null;
     byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    try {
        // create FileInputStream object
        fin = new FileInputStream(file);



        // Reads up to certain bytes of data from this input stream into an array of bytes.
        fin.read(fileContent);
        //create string from byte array
        String s = new String(fileContent);
        System.out.println("File content: " + s);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while reading file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        // close the streams using close method
        try {
            if (fin != null) {
                fin.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
        }
    }
    byte[] fileContent1 = null;

    /*end of modify */
    if(flag==true){
        fileContent1=zipBytes("Sample.pdf", fileContent);//document.getmimetype
    }else{
        fileContent1 = fileContent;
    }
    javaMail.sendEmail(to, cc, subject, content, fileContent1);


}

public static byte[] zipBytes(String filename, byte[] input) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
    entry.setSize(input.length);
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
    zos.write(input);
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();



    return baos.toByteArray();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

package com.mail.send;

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
```

//mailimpl
    public class JavaMail {

```
@Autowired
JavaMailSender mailSender;

public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
    return mailSender;
}

public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

String from = "pqr@gmail.com";

public void sendEmail(String to, String cc, String subject, String content,
        byte [] attachement) {
    try {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true);
        mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(from);
        mimeMessageHelper.setTo(to);
        mimeMessageHelper.setCc(cc);
        mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessageHelper.setText(content, true);
    //  mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(attachement.getName(), attachement);

        //ByteArrayDataSource byteArrayDataSource=new ByteArrayDataSource(attachement, "application/zip");
        ByteArrayDataSource byteArrayDataSource = null;
        if(attachement.length > 10){
             byteArrayDataSource=new ByteArrayDataSource(attachement, "application/zip");
             mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(byteArrayDataSource.getName(), byteArrayDataSource);

            }else{
                 byteArrayDataSource=new ByteArrayDataSource(attachement, "application/pdf");
                 mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(byteArrayDataSource.getName()+".pdf", byteArrayDataSource);

            }
        //mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(byteArrayDataSource.getName(), byteArrayDataSource);

        System.out.println("Start of mail");
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        System.out.println("End of mail");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mail.send" />

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="JavaMail" class="com.mail.send.JavaMail">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>

<!--    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    max upload size in bytes
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> 20MB

    max size of file in memory (in bytes)
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> 1MB

</bean> -->
</beans>
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine. only change that I made is 'byteArrayDataSource.getName()' instead of this I gave my file name because it was returning empty string.