# Send generated report as email attachment in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I want to be able to send report generated with *JasperReports* as attachment.  Currently in my application I am able to view the report using **JasperReportsViewResolver** below is my configuration

```
@Bean
public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
  JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/static/jasper/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jrxml");
  resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
  resolver.setViewNames("rpt_*");
  resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
}
```

I was not able to get the input resource from this viewresolver so below is the idea I'm thinking of but I'm not sure it is the best way

```
 JasperDesign jasperDesign =  JRXmlLoader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasper/rpt_media.jrxml"));
 JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
 JRDataSource reportData = new JREmptyDataSource();

 Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 parameters.put("reportTitle", "dfa dafdf d dfd");

 OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);

 JasperReportsUtils.renderAsPdf(report, parameters, reportData, stream);
```

after saving the report to random file I do read it and send as attachment.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the below to be the best way

```
    JRDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportList);

    Resource report = new ClassPathResource("static/jasper/rpt_report.jasper");

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report.getInputStream(), Collections.EMPTY_MAP,ds);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, baos);
    DataSource aAttachment =  new ByteArrayDataSource(baos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

    helper.setTo("xxxxxx");

    helper.setFrom("xxxxx");
    helper.setSubject("Testing Email");

    String text = "Testing Email";

    helper.setText(text, false);

    helper.addAttachment("report.pdf",aAttachment);

    mailSender.send(message);
```

Comment: what are the particular library imports jar files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286295/how-to-send-the-mail-with-attachment-in-spring
this url worked for me